# Creating a block device entry from an offset of another block device

Tags: c, linux

I am writing what I can guess would be classed as a file system, that's 100% compatible with LUKS/dm-crypt, except for a 128 byte metadata block in the beginning of the device. I don't see a way to specify an offset from `crypt_load`, `crypt_format` or `crypt_activate_by_passphrase`.

So, in the search of a more general solution: **How can I, from C (or C++), create a block device pointing to an offset of another block device?**

Comment: The `losetup` command can do that (with `-o` and `--sizelimit`). Not a C solution, but perhaps a starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`devicemapper` can do this. I don't know about the C interface, but you can read the source code of `dmsetup`.

In particular:

```
echo "$SIZE linear /dev/$DEVICE $OFFSET" | dmsetup create NEWDEVICE
```

will create a device named `/dev/mapper/NEWDEVICE`.

The funny thing is that `$SIZE` and `$OFFSET` are in number of blocks, not bytes. And block size is usually 512 bytes, so your offset of 128 bytes will be impossible to do. But anyway, you do not want to misalign the blocks in your device, do you?

**UPDATE**: Ok, I looked at it. `dmsetup` uses this cool library `libdevmapper` to do the hard work.

Comment: I'll take a peek at the API, and the changing the offset isn't harder than changing a #define ;)

Comment: @ChlorideCull: Cool, but note that if the library gets messy you can always call the command directly. For this particular case I don't think anybody would object.